# Oracle Stored Procedure - How to compare type NUMBER with intergers?

Tags: sql, if-statement, stored-procedures, oracle11g

I have following stored procedure. Parameter FLAG_ passed in is  only allowed to accept null, 0 or 1. But the condition checking (FLAG_ != 0 OR FLAG_ != 1) doesn't work. I guess this is because type for FLAG_ is NUMBER which include float. Is there a way to compare NUMBER to INT ?

```
create or replace PROCEDURE "ADD_RMV_FLAG"
(
  TEXT OUT VARCHAR2 
, FLAG_ IN NUMBER -- empty, 0 and 1 only values accepted.
) AS

BEGIN
-- input pramameters checking
IF FLAG_ is not null
THEN
   IF (FLAG_ is not null AND (FLAG_ != 0 OR FLAG_ != 1))
   THEN
     raise_application_error(-20001, 'ERROR: only empty, 0 or 1 is accepted   
     for FLAG. Passed in ' || FLAG_);
   END IF;
 END IF;
END ADD_RMV_FLAE
```

Comment: `doesn't work` ? I bet my money on `OR` used instead of `AND` ...

Comment: What you're doing should work fine. However, I don't believe your code will compile because in the last line you have `END ADD_RMV_FLAE` when the name of the routine is `ADD_RMV_FLAG` and the names need to match. `AND` @Sebas is right - use `AND` instead of `OR`.

Comment: @Sebas Thanks for your response. AND is correct.

Comment: @Bob ADD_RMV_FLAE was type  error. Originally it was correct in my Oracle client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression:

```
IF (FLAG_ is not null AND (FLAG_ != 0 OR FLAG_ != 1))
```

will always evaluate to TRUE.  If flag is 0, then you get "false OR true".  If flag is 3.1415926535 . . . , then you get "true or true".

You want `AND`, or better yet:  `NOT IN`:

```
IF (FLAG_ is not null AND FLAG_ NOT IN (0, 1))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It is a graceful solution. Originally I was trying with IF(FLAG NOT IN (null, 0, 1)).